# How to add header to a bokeh dashboard in python?

Tags: python, header, bokeh, dashboard

I created a dashboard in bokeh, but how I can I ad a universal header to it?

[image]
I did a lot of research before, but it seems like nobody asked this simple question before.

Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Eugene mentioned you can use a div-container to set the title and later set it in the column output.

Here some example code that might be helpful to understand:

```
output_file("slider.html")
title = Div(text='<h1 style="text-align: center">Example Header</h1>')
p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab1 = Panel(child=p1, title="circle")

p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="line")

tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2])

layout = column(title, tabs, sizing_mode='scale_width')

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your dashboard in a `column` where the first item is a `Div` with the header text.